# Generate ws-address WSDL with CXF

Tags: java, web-services, wsdl, cxf

I am creating (or trying to create) a java-first web service with CXF (3.1.11) that uses ws-address (WSA).  What I would expect to see is inclusion of the WSA components in the WSDL that gets generated.  Before getting into specific configs and code, I want to validate my core understanding of how I expect CXF to work.  Are the WSA elements supposed to be generated in the WSDL?  Things I've tried:

Adding the address "feature" through configuration with <wsa:address>.  (Is this a bus or endpoint feature?  Docs aren't clear to me.)

Adding the address feature via code using the annotation  @org.apache.cxf.features.Features

Adding the java-ws annotation @javax.xml.soap.Addressing(enabled=true) -- the javadoc on this annotation states that its requires the WSA components in the WSDL.

Adding a policy that requires the use of WSA.

What am I missing?  Any hints are greatly appreciated.